# What is a PCI device?

Tags: pci, lspci

When I run the `man lspci` command, I get:

```
 lspci - list all PCI devices
```

But I don't know what a PCI device is. Can anyone explain?

Comment: peripheral component interconnect: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A PCI device is basically any piece of computer hardware connected to your motherboard. **P**eripheral **C**omponent **I**nterconnect was a standard introduced by Intel in order to easily integrate peripheral devices such as audio cards or video cards into your motherboard. If you look inside your computer a PCI connector is usually identified by a long strip of raised copper connectors- namely the PCI Bus.

The command *lspci* lists all the pci hardware connected to your computer- from audio cards to video cards, network cards and so on and so forth.

Answer based on: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/what-is-a-pci-device

Please look into the above link to further expand your knowledge about the subject.